# Dependencies could not be resolved (in Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I use cocoapods to manage package dependencies and my device is Macbook Pro 2021, and suddenly I couldn't build my project
[image: error messages as follow]

I had tried cleanning build folder and DerivedData in Xcode but these didn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That is not cocoapods — that’s the Swift Package Manager

Comment: And the message is telling you where to look. There's no reason that cleaning the build folder or the like would change this. How exactly are you requiring swift-algorithms (I expect you either have a requirement mismatch, or you're pulling from the wrong place).

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for your answer. I am the newcomer in this project and swift-algorithms is useless for the project indeed. So I just build the project successfully by deleting  that package.